# Rhino mocks AssertWasNotCalled extracted to generic method fails

Tags: c#, .net, generics, extension-methods, rhino-mocks

I was trying to implement common extension "shortcut" method to check if `Dispose()` was not called on the mock (Rhino):

```
public static void AssertNotDisposed<T>(this T disposable) where T : IDisposable =>
    disposable.AssertWasNotCalled(x => x.Dispose());
```

but it not so simple as I expected.

```
var mock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Stream>();
mock.Dispose();
mock.AssertNotDisposed();
```

`AssertNotDisposed` call does not notice `mock.Dispose()` if mock was made for derived type not for `IDisposable` directly.

I could somehow justify a failure if my method argument was exactly `IDisposable` (looks like Rhino differentiates not just mock instances but even types of references they are accessed with).

If the same assumption is valid for generics maybe dynamic (reflection) construction of action and method call (as not generic) can help I'm not sure how to do it just now.

So what is the real cause of the problem? Why `AssertNotDisposed()` ignores preceding `Dispose()`?

Comment: Your call is effectively the same as `mock.AssertWasNotCalled(x => ((IDisposable) x).Dispose())`, which does not work either, unless you call `((IDisposable) mock).Dispose()`. In the extension method, `T.Dispose()` must necessarily resolve to `IDisposable.Dispose()`, because the method has only one implementation (it's not instantiated separately for every `T`), and apparently Rhino matches things rather exactly. I don't see any obvious way to fix this in the extension method, unless through very ugly reflection to find the implementing method of an interface.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hence argument with `where T : IDisposable` is the same as specify it `IDisposable disposable`. Is it correct? It seems I've forgotten smth about generics assuming they do not cast types.

Comment: No, it's not the same thing -- inside the method, `T != IDisposable`. However, when you use the instance to call methods of `IDisposable`, the call is made through the method table of `IDisposable`, not `T`. This is different from calling `Stream.Dispose()` directly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Deep magic. Still my common sense was on the right way from the beginning. Thank you for clarification.  You could post your comments as an answer and I mark it tomorrow if nobody will post even more detailed one.

Comment: There's actually even more deep magic going on -- the only reason your method even "works" in the first place is that `Stream` is a `MarshalByRefObject`. If you try the same exercise on another type that implements `IDisposable` through a non-virtual `Dispose` method, Rhino will give an error that the method is not overridable, and this is true also for the direct `.AssertWasNotCalled(x => x.Dispose())` call. I'm not sure Rhino can even do this (verify calls of interface methods implemented by non-virtual methods). If it can, then not through the direct approach.

Comment: @JeroenMostert No, it's strictly for interfaces or virtual methods of classes according to documentation as I remember.